# In fixest::etable, is there a way to change the font size and the footnote for the p-value?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, fixest

In fixest::etable, is there a way to change the font size and the footnote for the p-value?
I am currently looking into documentation and such to be able to output a pdf table in etable with my preferred settings.

I would like to adjust the font size of the table, as the data I am working with has a lot of variables and will not fit in A4 size. Also, by default in etable, the footnote for p-value significance is `Signif. Codes: ***: 0.001, **: 0.01, *: 0.05, , .: 0.1`. Is there any way to change this? Specifically, I want to use LaTeX code to display `*** $p < 0.001$; ** $p < 0.01$; * $p < 0.05$; + $p < 0.1$`.

Here is the test data.

```
mtcars %>%
    feols(c(mpg, wt) ~ sw(disp, hp)) %>%
    esttex(
        title = "Test Model",
        style.tex = style.tex(
            model.title = "",
            var.title = "\\midrule Vars",
            depvar.title = "",
            fixef.title = "",
            fixef.suffix = "\\midrule fe",
            stats.title = "\\midrule stats",
            yesNo = "yes"
        ),
        drop = "Intercept",
        digits = "r3",
        digits.stats = "r3",
        order = c("hp", "disp"),
        dict = c(hp = "HP", "disp" = "DISP"),
        signifCode = c("***" = 0.001, "**" = 0.01, "*" = 0.05, "." = 0.10)
    )
```

[image: picture]

Comment: `etable()` is a quick convenience function. You'd probably be better using a package specifically devoted to creating summary tables. `gtsummary` is a good one. It uses `broom` under the hood which can handle fixest objects.